# Rails 3.2.3 wants sqlite3 gem on mysql production env

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rake, capistrano

I have a Rails 3.2.3 application which gets deployed with Capistrano. Until now, this workflow worked perfectly for several months now. But since the last deployment of the latest changes, the `rake db:migrate` action hangs because it can't find the SQLite3 gem and adapter.

```
executing "cd /home/*/*/*/releases/20120425232058 && bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
executing command
rake aborted!
Please install the sqlite3 adapter: `gem install activerecord-sqlite3-adapter` (sqlite3 is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.)
```

the thing is, the application is running on MySQL. I have in my Gemfile:

```rb
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'omniauth-openid'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'pusher'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'capistrano'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

group :development, :production do
  gem 'mysql2'
end

group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
end
```

and the database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: *****_development
  pool: 5
  username: *****
  password: *****
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: *****_production
  pool: 5
  username: *****
  password: *****
  host: localhost
```

the application runs without problems in production mode on my local machine.

why is Rails trying to install SQLite ?

Comment: can you post your gemfile and database.yml?

Comment: Check that you have not got sqlite gem in your gemfile or if you have then make sure it is in the test group

Comment: the sqlite gem has never been in the Gemfile. the above config has worked for months. it only just now started to ask for it.

Answer (score 2):

I beleive you have sqlite specified in your config/database.yml

Comment: nope. i have `adapter: mysql2` for both development and production in database.yml

Comment: and the test environment too?

Comment: test env isn't defined. it's not necessary on the production machine, is it ?

Answer (score 1):

My bad guys. Something went wrong in the Capistrano recipe. Thanks though for your answers !

Comment: Please post the changes you had to make in your Capistrano file(s) in order to resolve the problem.

Comment: the Capistrano recipe is taken from the Railscasts [Deploying to a VPS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps) tutorial, where the `database.yml` file is not in the Git repo but is copied with Capistrano. I forgot to edit the `database.yml` file on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the list of changes in the new deployment? Perhaps it's an issue with one of the gems that also use `ActiveRecord`?

Comment: the change wasn't ActiveRecord related. I made some changes in `application.js` file.